# SCSS files in React Native - import and usage

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, sass

I'm new to React Native and I wanted to implement a floating button in my React Native App like the one here: https://bit.dev/khaledebdelli/components/fancy-floaty-button

I tried importing the package for the button using npm from Terminal but it said the file didn't exist so I saved the scss file provided in my project directory.

I exactly followed the instructions from this link: https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer in order to use scss files in React Native.

However, the floating button did not appear in my app. Here is what I tried to do in code:

Inside BackButton.js:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
{/* CSS file imported in below line of code */}
import styles from './styling/floatButton.scss'

export default function BackButton(props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    console.log(props.title)
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.btn}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(props.to, props.toTransfer)}
        >
            <Text>
                {props.title}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Inside hash-tables.js where I imported BackButton.js and rendered the BackButton component:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import BackButton from '../Components/BackButton';

{*/Below line of code is inside the render function of a class component/*}
    <BackButton title='Previous' to='Topics' />
```

This is what I see in my app instead of the floating button:

[image]

Would appreciate it if someone could point out where I may have gone wrong :)

Comment: Can you please show what your styles file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you don't have sass installed correctly, I usually just do: "npm install node-sass" in the front-end and works everytime :)